# Why is a REIT (Real estate investment trust) able to grow and appreciate, given that it is not able to retain its earnings?

Tags: real-estate, reit

REITs have to distribute out most of their earnings to shareholders. This deprives REITs the needed cash to reinvest into their business to grow organically. Wouldn't this stunt REITs' business growth and price appreciation? If REITs need capital, they ask money from shareholders. This is bad for shareholders and hold back the share price.

How do REITs' price appreciate, given that they do not retain earnings to reinvest back into their business like ordinary companies?

Comment: If REITs need money to expand, don’t they just borrow it from a bank?

Comment: Although REITs have a high payout ratio, their retained earnings are/can be used towards investing in other properties in which they collect rent; thus allowing them to grow. If they need the funds they finance it.

Comment: @NuWin that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

REITs increase in value because the underlying assets (the real estate) increase in value.